# select text from multiple combinations of text within a dataframe R

Tags: r, text, subset, tidytext

I want to subset data based on a text code that is used in numerous combinations throughout one column of a df. I checked first all the variations by creating a table.

```
 list <-  as.data.frame(table(EQP$col1))
```

[image]

I want to search within the dataframe for the text "EFC" (even when combined with other letters) and subset these rows so that I have a resultant dataframe that looks like this.

[image]

I have looked through this question here, but this does not answer the question. I have reviewed the tidytext package, but this does not seem to be the solution either.

[How to Extract keywords from a Data Frame in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45371139/how-to-extract-keywords-from-a-data-frame-in-r)

Comment: Are you trying to just subset the rows or to do something else as well? Can you provide a [working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: just subset the rows that have "EFC" (in any combination) in column 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `grepl`.

Considering your `data.frame` is called `df` and the column to subset on is `col1`

```
df <- data.frame(
    col1 = c("eraEFC", "dfs", "asdj, aslkj", "dlja,EFC,:LJ)"),
    stringsAsFactors = F
)

df[grepl("EFC", df$col1), , drop = F]
```

Comment: Hi. I tried this - package ‘grepl’ is not available (for R version 3.6.1)

Comment: `grepl` is not a package, it is a base R function. What did you try exactly?

Answer (score 1):

Another option besides the mentioned solution by Gallarus would be:

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
df %>% filter(str_detect(Var1, "EFC"))
```

As described by Sam Firke in this post:

[Selecting rows where a column has a string like 'hsa..' (partial string match)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13043928/selecting-rows-where-a-column-has-a-string-like-hsa-partial-string-match)

Comment: What if you wanted to include more than one "text", 

df %>% filter(str_detect(Var1, "EFC", "ADE")) doesnt work...

Comment: Something like df %>% filter(str_detect(Var1, pattern = "EFC|ADE")) would work (if you want to return the df containing either of those partial strings.